# How to Solve a Rails Enum Error When Prefix Doesn't Work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are many Rails enum questions/answers on here, but I haven't yet found a solution to my particular issue.

Background: I had an application form that was working fine.  I started playing around with some regular expressions, and testing them out by submitting the form.  Suddenly, I got this error:

```
You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "ApplicationForm", 
but this will generate a instance method "Submitted?", which is already 
defined by another enum.
```

The actual code is:

```
enum status: { Submitted: 0, Accepted: 1, Refused: 2, NeedsRevision: 3, Edited: 4 }
```

After reviewing S.O., I changed the code to this:

```
enum status: { Submitted: 0, Accepted: 1, Refused: 2, NeedsRevision: 3, Edited: 4 }, prefix: true
```

However, now the error simply changes to this:

```
You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "ApplicationForm", 
but this will generate a instance method "status_Submitted?", which is already 
defined by another enum.
```

I cannot figure out why this application form was working fine for the last 3 weeks, yet why now, today, while trying to play with some regular expressions, suddenly I'm getting this error.  Even after removing the regular expressions, and restarting the server, the errors remain.

Note that in the entire app, there is only one 'enum' definition.  The one above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This actually sounds like some sort of app reloading issue.

Comment: I had tried restarting the server a number of times, but it didn't seem to work.  But eventually, based on what I did below, it did start to work.

Comment: FYI, for all those having similar enum issues, read this.  It's a good article that explains how enums work:

https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum

Comment: Gonna put this as an answer so I can copy/paste my console...

Comment: @MonroeMann can you show how to reproduce the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your reloading issue by having the `^` anchor and the `enum` before the `validates` (so it is loaded before the exception), triggering the exception, then fixing the anchor issue but not reloading the console, then using the class will trigger the enum issue because the enum had already been loaded before the regex anchor exception:

```
main> .cat app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  enum name: { foo: 1 }
  validates :name, format: { with: /^/ }
end
main> Foo.first
ArgumentError: The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?
from /Users/jk/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.5/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:39:in `check_options_validity'
main> 
main> # FIX THE FILE!
main> 
main> .cat app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  enum name: { foo: 1 }
  validates :name, format: { with: /\A/ }
end
main> Foo.first
ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "name" on the model "Foo", but this will generate a instance method "foo?", which is already defined by another enum.
from /Users/jk/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.5/lib/active_record/enum.rb:301:in `raise_conflict_error'
```

If I reload the console then all works as expected from then on:

```
main> reload!
Reloading...
true
main> Foo.first
  Foo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Foo:0x0000000106eda628 id: 1, name: nil, ...>
```